# display data using ajax datatable with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to display data from database in my view using ajax.
But i receve this message:  DataTables warning: table id=users - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

this is my controller :

```
public function listUser(){
     if ($this->session->userdata("success"))
        {

            // les Variables de datatable
           //
           $draw = intval($this->input->post("draw"));
           //
           $start = intval($this->input->post("start"));
           $length = intval($this->input->post("length"));
         $user = $this->UserModel->getUsers();
         $data = array();
         foreach( $user as $r) {        
                                        $tab[] = array();
                                        $tab[] =    $r->username;
                                        $tab[] =$r->usersurname;
                                        $tab[] =$r->useremail;
                                        $tab[] =$r->date_create;
                                        $tab[] =$r->Num_tel;
                                        $tab[] =$r->userright;                                                              
                                        $tab[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$r->user_id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Modifier</button>';  
                                        $tab[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$r->user_id.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Supprimer</button>';  
                                       $data = $tab;
                            }

                            $output = array(
                                "draw" => $draw,
                                    "recordsTotal" => count($user),
                                    "recordsFiltered" => count($user),
                                    "data" => $data
                                );

                            echo json_encode($output);
                            exit();

                        }
//    $this->load->view('users/listUser',['user'=>$user]);
   //     }
     else
        {
            return redirect('Login');  
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be in the loop section, every time the loop passes in this line `$tab[] = array();` your not reseting the variable but actually appending a new array to the `$tab`, you should use `$tab = array();` to reset the variable, and in the end `$data[] = $tab;` to append the `$tab` data to the `$data` variable.

```
 $data = array();
 foreach( $user as $r) {        
    $tab = array();
    $tab[] = $r->username;
    $tab[] = $r->usersurname;
    $tab[] = $r->useremail;
    $tab[] = $r->date_create;
    $tab[] = $r->Num_tel;
    $tab[] = $r->userright;                                                              
    $tab[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$r->user_id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Modifier</button>';  
    $tab[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$r->user_id.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Supprimer</button>';  
    $data[] = $tab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok thank you, but i receve another warning: DataTables warning: table id=users - Requested unknown parameter '6' for row 0, column 6. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

this is my views :

```
<table class="display responsive no-wrap table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column dataTable no-footer" id="users" width="100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Nom</th>
                                                    <th>Prenom</th>
                                                    <th>E-mail</th>              
                                                    <th>Date de creation</th>
                                                    <th>Téléphone</th>               
                                                    <th>Droit</th>
                                                     <th>Modifier</th>
                                                    <th>Supprimer</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                        </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function() {

            let mouvementTable =  $("#users").DataTable({
                                 buttons: [{
                        extend: "print",
                        className: "btn dark btn-outline"
                    },  {
                        extend: "pdf",
                        className: "btn green btn-outline"
                    }, {
                        extend: "excel",
                        className: "btn yellow btn-outline "
                    }, {
                        extend: "csv",
                        className: "btn purple btn-outline "
                    }],


                "ajax": {
                    url : "http://localhost/logistock/index.php/ControllerUser/listUser",
                    "type": "POST"
                },

                order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
                 "select": {
                     "style":    'multi',
                    "selector": 'td:first-child'
                 },
               "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",

                "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]],
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/French.json"
                }



            });  

        });


    </script>
```